# Properly Merging And Formatting Two Files Into One (C) (With Parameters)

Tags: merge, formatting, vertices

I've been trying to figure out a good way to do this for several months, but still have not figured out a good way to make it work. I've tried many different routes but still cannot seem to manage one that suits my needs.

I'm sure that this is actually an easy fix and that someone out there will be able to help me accomplish this.

I have a program that takes two text documents that merges and formats them into one.

One document looks like this:

```
1 = 0.61 0.42 
2 = 1.00 0.51 
3 = 0.83 0.94 
4 = 0.43 1.00 
5 = -0.00 0.37 
6 = 0.25 0.00 
7 = 0.59 0.11
```

And the other looks like this:

```
1
2
3
1
3
4
1
4
5
1
5
6
1
6
7
```

Basically, what I want to do is for every number in the second file, it's number get's replaced with the contents of the number and its properties from the first file.

So, the second file would look something like this once the program works:

```
1 = 0.61 0.42 
2 = 1.00 0.51 
3 = 0.83 0.94 
1 = 0.61 0.42 
3 = 0.83 0.94 
4 = 0.43 1.00 
1 = 0.61 0.42 
4 = 0.43 1.00 
5 = -0.00 0.37
1 = 0.61 0.42 
5 = -0.00 0.37
6 = 0.25 0.00 
1 = 0.61 0.42 
6 = 0.25 0.00 
7 = 0.59 0.11
```

Here is my code in case anyone is curious. Just remember that it's been through a lot, so some code has been 'commented' out. There was a bigger block of code before, but it was mostly work I tried that didn't work.

```
#include <iostream>

FILE *vertices;
FILE *triangles;
FILE *after;

int vertex;

int triangle;
int triPos[] = {};

float texX, texY;
float texXPos[] = {};
float texYPos[] = {};

int main()
    {
    vertices = fopen("vertices.txt", "r");
    triangles = fopen("triangles.txt", "r");
    after = fopen("after.txt", "w");

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
        fscanf(vertices, "%d = %f %f \n", &vertex, &texX, &texY);

        fscanf(triangles, "%d \n", &triangle);

        //set the right texture index
        texXPos[i] = texX;
        texYPos[i] = texY;

        //set the right triangle index
        triPos[i] = triangle;

        //prints the right texture coordinates
        //coordinates are working, but don't match yet

        fprintf(after, "%d = %.2f %.2f \n", triPos[i], texXPos[i], texYPos[i]);
        //fprintf(after, "%.2f %.2f \n", texXPos[i], texYPos[i]);
        //fprintf(after, "%d \n", triPos[i]);
        };

    fclose(vertices);
    fclose(triangles);
    fclose(after);

    return 0;
    };
```

If anyone is really curious bout the variable names, I'm working on editing OBJ files.

I appreciate any help at all to this point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before anyone finds this topic and replies on it, I just wanted to let you know that I've resolved my problem. Instead of reading in the contents of the first document by %d, I've found that it's easier to read by %s. I'm getting the whole strings and then putting them into an array. This way, I can actually check to see what the number in the second file is equal to from the first. It works, and I'm glad I've found the answer on my own.  Thanks anyways.